# Reading Array multiple times gives an error javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

I am trying to make a website that need a google map on it with some markers
I have a problem with reading a javascript 2D array multiple time it gives me error

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

and here its my code

```
function initialize() {
          var locations = [
          //'City',LatLng,LatLng,Zoom
          ['Egypt', 26.820553, 30.802498, 6], //Center of whole map
          ['Alexandria', 'Egypt'], //pointer
          ['Mansoura', 'Egypt'], //pointer
          ['Assiut', 'Egypt'] //pointer
          ];

          var mapOptions = {
              zoom: locations[0][3],
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[0][1], locations[0][2]),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
          mapOptions);

          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

          var marker, i;
          var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
          var image = 'flag.png';

          for (i = 1; i < locations.length; i++) {
              geocoder.geocode({ 'address': locations[i][0] + ' ' + locations[i][1] }, function (results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                          map: map,
                          icon: image,
                          position: results[0].geometry.location,
                          title: locations[i][0]
                      });

                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                          return function () {
                              infowindow.setContent('<b style="font-size:30px;">' + locations[i][0] + '</b>'
                                  + '<br><b>Starting Date:</b> 11/5/2012'
                                  + '<br><b>Ending Date:</b> 30/5/2012'
                                  + '<br><a href="google.com">Event Website</a>');
                              infowindow.open(map, marker);
                          }
                      })(marker, i));
                  }
              });
          }
      }

      function loadScript() {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA6yYH66F1L3NgHAobufuUF6l-jjVCLwfE&sensor=false&' +
          'callback=initialize';
          document.body.appendChild(script);
      }

      window.onload = loadScript;
```

I got the error in this section
when I am trying to read locations[i][0] many times.

```
for (i = 1; i < locations.length; i++) {
              geocoder.geocode({ 'address': locations[i][0] + ' ' + locations[i][1] }, function (results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                          map: map,
                          icon: image,
                          position: results[0].geometry.location,
                          title: locations[i][0]
                      });

                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                          return function () {
                              infowindow.setContent('<b style="font-size:30px;">' + locations[i][0] + '</b>'
                                  + '<br><b>Starting Date:</b> 11/5/2012'
                                  + '<br><b>Ending Date:</b> 30/5/2012'
                                  + '<br><a href="google.com">Event Website</a>');
                              infowindow.open(map, marker);
                          }
                      })(marker, i));
                  }
              });
          }
```

and if there is anyway that I can handle this code in c# code behind it will be nice

Comment: Don't you mean `for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)`? Starting the iterator at 1 means the last iteration will exceed the length of the array.

Comment: I mean when I'm trying to read locations[i][0] many times it gives error.
and I want loop start from 1 because 0 is the center of my map

Comment: OK, yeah to be honest that wouldn't cause an error. If the error occurs at `locations[i][0]` and says "Cannot read property '0' of undefined", it simply means there is no object at position `i` in the `locations` array. What is the value of `i` when the error is thrown? Put a breakpoint on that line in your debugger (Firebug / Chrome dev tools etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ignore previous comment about `results`]

The problem is that you're referencing `i` in the geocode() callback.  The geocode() method is asynchronous - i.e. your callback is called *after* the for-loop has already finished.  And at that time, `i` = 4, meaning locations[i] is undefined.

You should read up on how closures work if that doesn't make sense, but basically the solution is to put the code inside your for-loop into a separate function and pass it the location entry you want to work with, like so:

```
function geocodeLocation(location) {
  geocoder.geocode({ 'address': location[0] + ' ' + location[1] },
    function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          map: map,
          icon: image,
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          title: location[0]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
            infowindow.setContent('<b style="font-size:30px;">' + location[0] + '</b>'
              + '<br><b>Starting Date:</b> 11/5/2012'
              + '<br><b>Ending Date:</b> 30/5/2012'
              + '<br><a href="google.com">Event Website</a>');
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
        })(marker, i));
      }
    }
  );
}


for (var i = 1; i < locations.length; i++) {
  geocodeLocation(locations[i]);
}
```

Comment: I got the code from google
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingStatusCodes

Comment: updated answer - I was incorrect in thinking it was `results`.  Tested your code and figured out the problem is as noted above.

Comment: classic closure in for loop problem

Comment: Yes, broofa, you beat me to it, asynch callback of the function causes  the variable i to be the lenght of locations when the geocoder.geocode calls the callback.

Comment: I though all my code under for-loop. gj your code looks clear :D